# Como hacer que este meta box aparezca en varios post type?

Tags: wordpress

este es un pequeño fragmento del codigo, lo que quiero saber es como 
   hacer que este metabox no solo aparezca en post si no también en varios post type que yó he creado. alguna ayuda?

```
 $prefix = 'std_';

    $meta_box = array(
        'id' => 'my-meta-box',
        'title' => 'Agregar Opciones',
        'page' => 'post',
        'context' => 'normal',
        'priority' => 'high',
        'fields' => array(
            array(
                'name' => 'Alt',            
                'id' => $prefix . 'alt',
                'type' => 'text',
```

Lo que quiero es saber si hay alguna forma de hacerlo con este codigo no con otros, este funciona muy bien solo que este metabox aparece en post.

alguna idea de como editar la linea: `'page' => 'post',` para agregar varios custom post type, he editado y no he logrado resultados.

Comment: ¿`add_meta_box` no te sirve? Si no, observa [aquí la respuesta dada por amabil](https://wordpress.org/ideas/topic/add-meta-box-to-multiple-post-types)

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres agregar metaboxes de forma dinámica, la mejor forma sería **usando la función nativa de Wordpress** **[`add_meta_box`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_meta_box/)**.

Defines un arreglo `$tipos_post` en el que incluyes separados por comas los tipos de post a los que quieres añadirle el meta_box y haces un bucle para añadir el meta_box a cada tipo de post que haya en `$tipos_post` :

```
function add_custom_meta_box()
{

    $tipos_post = array ( 'post', 'page', 'tipo_personalizado' );

    foreach( $tipos_post as $tipo_post )
    {
        add_meta_box(
            'custom_meta_box', // $id
            'Custom Meta Box', // $title 
            'show_custom_meta_box', // $callback
             $tipo_post,
            'normal', // $context
            'high' // $priority
        );
    }
}

add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'add_custom_meta_box');
```

No te *cases* con un tipo de código si existen otras funciones que podrían resolver mejor el problema, más aún si son funciones nativas del CMS que estás usando.